# How to combine two Crossentropies

Tags: tensorflow

based ob the loss function in the seq2seq-model ("sequence_loss_by_example" - context here translate.py) I am trying to value the cost of a real-values-estimator. I want the model to guess real values that might vary heavily in scale.

Now, my questions is: Could you feedback whether the combination of the two cross entropies makes sense the way I implemented them. Can I just append them and then add_n them?

```
for logit, target, weight in zip(logits, targets, weights):
    real_target   = target[:, 0:11]
    real_logit    = logit[:, 0:11]
    anteil_target = target[:, 11:]
    anteil_logit  = logit[:, 11:]

    total_size += 1.1 * weight
    crossent          = weight * nn_ops.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(real_logit, real_target, name="main_bits_loss")
    crossent_anteil   = 0.1 * weight * nn_ops.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(anteil_logit, anteil_target, name="anteil_bits_loss")

    log_perp_list.append(crossent)
    log_perp_list.append(crossent_anteil)

log_perps = math_ops.add_n(log_perp_list) / total_size

return log_perps
```

And also: To debug, how can I give this tensor a name?

```
real_target   = target[:, 0:11]
```

Something like:

```
real_target   = target[:, 0:11]
real_target.name('name_goes_here')
```

?

Thx a bunch
Phillip

Answer (score 1):

The [:, 0:11] notation internally calls tf.slice(), which does take a name parameter. In your case, you should be able to do something like this:

`real_target = tf.slice(target, [0, 0], [-1, 11], name="real_target")`